# Unable to fetch excel spreadsheet data from GitHub into React JS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, fetch

I want to fetch data from excel sheet to React JS app, where spreadsheet is place into different GitHub location.
When I fetch excel record then it is showing no records as Array(0).
Some code snippets are mentioned below, anybody would give your suggestion here in code to do any modification if required.

```
function ImportXLSXData() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    let json;
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://github.com/ExcelSheet/blob/master/Spreadsheet/Sheet.xlsx")
            .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
            .then(ab => {
                const wb = XLSX.read(ab, { type: "array" });
                console.log('wb: ', wb);
                const ws = wb.Sheets[wb.SheetNames[0]];
                json = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);
                setData(json);
            });
    }, []);

    return data;
}
export default ImportXLSXData;
```

I am getting output like:
[In response Array(0) is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NwKr.png)

Comment: Are you using the FileReader()?

Comment: Not using FileReader(), same as exact code is mentioned above post

Comment: is this github url is public?

Comment: Yes, it's public repository within organization.

Comment: mention the sheet name directly while fetching sheet data wb.Sheets("Sheetname")

Comment: While mentioning sheet name directly it's showing undefined!

Comment: can you place dummy Excel and place it in blob and try to fetch that one. may be the file that you are fetching is corrupted.

Comment: Yes I tried by putting dummy file to GitHub but same response as Array(0), even it's not showing sheet name.